# Android to BB10 Porting Phone Gap Application (Same Origin Policy Issue)

Tags: javascript, android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I'm trying to port phonegap Android app to bb10, The issue is android web-view doesn't follow Same Origin Policy so app works fine on Android. But seems BB10 web view follows Same Origin Policy. so application doesn't work properly in BB10 devices. Is there any way to disable this SOP in BB10 within Android code or java script?

**EDIT:**
Small Clarification on this:

Phone gap application opens a HTML/Java Script file inside a web view. So now I'm going to port Phone gap Android app to BB10. Standard web browsers follow "[Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)" But seems android web view doesn't follow the policy so thats why we are able to call ajax request within web view.

but bb10 web view behaviour is different it seems. 
so is there any one who tried to port Android Phonegap application to BB10 successfully? And how to cater SOP in BB10?

Comment: I've only briefly worked with BB web apps, but I believe that there is a configuration file (possibly config.xml) where you list the allowed domains. You may try packaging that with it.

Comment: Thanks jprofitt, you are correct, there is a configuration white-list file and we can white-list domains in that file, I have already configured it, but here the context is different, cz I'm not directly developing BB app, just Porting android app to BB10.

Comment: Have you tried going ahead and including a config.xml in the root of your web code? I have no clue if it'll work, but it's worth a shot if you've not yet.

Comment: Yes jprofitt, its inside assets/www/config.xml, and I included this <access uri ="*" subdomains="true"/> which should allow all urls. but seems still BB web view applies SOP

Comment: I'm not experienced with Phone Gap but SOP is a good security practice. As a long time BlackBerry user and developer I would be disappointed if an application could bypass this without user agreement.